# Get unique superset of taxonomy terms from a list of custom posts in another hierarchical taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development

I have 2 custom taxonomies:

1. `catalog` (hierarchical)
2. `brand` (not hierarchical)

and a custom post type `solutions`.

We assume that we have such a structure:

sitename
-catalog
--sub_category_1
---solutions_1 (with brand_1, brand_2, brand_3)
---solutions_2 (with brand_1, brand_3, brand_4)
---solutions_3 (with brand_1, brand_2, brand_6)
--sub_category_2
---solutions_1 (with brand_1, brand_2, brand_3)
---solutions_4 (with brand_1, brand_4, brand_5)
---solutions_5 (with brand_7)
Who then has ideas how to get list of the unique `brand` terms for `solutions` in `sub_category_1` and `sub_category_2`

like if we on page 
`sub_category_1` - list must be: brand_1, brand_2, brand_3, brand_4, brand_6
`sub_category_2` - list must be: brand_1, brand_2, brand_3, brand_4, brand_5, brand_7

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when you are on the "page" `sub_category_1` you're looking at a standard archive for that term, you can do this...

The main query is already for the posts in `sub_category_1` so get a list of their IDs:

```
global $wp_query;
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $wp_query->posts, 'ID' );
```

Then you simply need to get a list of the terms from `brand` which are assigned to those posts:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'brand',
    'object_ids' => $post_ids,
) );
```

`$terms` will be an array of the `WP_Term` objects.